# When will GWT.create 2015 session videos online?

Tags: gwt

I want to watch the GWT.create 2015 sessions. I tried searching and didn't find anything. I found the GWT.create 2013 videos on the vaadinofficial youtube channel

Comment: I think they will post something only after the EU edition of the conference (27-28 jan).

Comment: Should be better posted in the google group or g+ community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The videos from GWT.create 2015 are being posted [here](http://gwtcreate.com/videos/index.html):

http://gwtcreate.com/videos/index.html

You can follow this [google+ community](https://plus.google.com/communities/116543000751323604177) as well

To subscribe to gwt create news and be notified when new videos are added go [here](http://gwtcreate.com/)